# AWS Cloudfront error with a lambda function

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular application running on lambda. Everything works fine accessing the application via the default domain given by AWS. The problem is when I try to use my custom domain with api-gateway. The browser seems to reach the lambda function but it throws the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec
```

Comment: Have you had a look in cloudfront logs? You might get some more info that will help you isolate the problem.

Comment: When I open CloudWatch logs of my lambda function there are no logs corresponding to the call. So I am assuming it does not reach the function.

Comment: Is some other name server sending the requests elsewhere and so you're not hitting the endpoint you expect? Something is handling the request and doesn't like it, when you figure that out, you'll almost certainly get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I already solved the problem, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a workaround. I used a serverless plugin called "[Serverless-domain-manager](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager)" that managed all the api-gateway configuration. That made the trick.

Hope this can help someone with a similar problem :)